# Forcing Input/Output encoding in Powershell to specific locale/codepage?

Tags: powershell, encoding, codepages, cjk

Working with files named in Japanese, and having trouble getting the encoding to process right.  After running

`chcp 50222
$OutputEncoding = [console]::outputencoding
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(50222)`

I can view Japanese properly on the console, and see things like "【お題箱】琴浦さん", it shows up fine in the `dir` listing as it should; and when redirecting it to a file, it stores properly.

HOWEVER, when I try to pipe things through the `tee` commandlet, to see it on the console and feed it to a file at the same time, I get "・・・・・｡・・・ｴ・ｵｦ・ｹ・・ｾ・・ｭ・" instead.

Best I can tell it's being re-encoded to something else between being output to the console, and being fed into `tee`....   so what can I do to fix that? Or is there something that'd do it better than tee?

(I've also noticed that things fed into tee from a 3rd-party download manager I have, have a significant delay until it shows up on the screen.  It will pause a while, show a few screens in a burst, pause for a while, show another few screens, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Based on `Get-Help Tee-Object -Full`, the command always uses Unicode (meaning UTF-16 LE or code page 1200) encoding.  Code page 50222 (iso-2022-jp/Japanese (JIS-Allow 1 byte Kana - SO/SI)) isn't a standard encoding that `Add-Content` or `Out-File` supports, either, so the common workaround of `Add-Content -Passthru` won't work.  I suspect you'll have to use a `StreamWriter` to even be able to write this encoding to a file.

I also have no idea if the console host that PowerShell uses actually respects `chcp.exe` or if it supports code page 50222.

Keep in mind, too, that internally all strings in .Net are Unicode (code page 1200).  If there are glyphs that cannot be represented with code page 1200 that can be represented with code page 50222, you may have problems.

Try duplicating `Tee-Object` with `ForEach-Object` and a StreamWriter:

```
$Encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(50222)
$Append = $true
$StreamWriter = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList $OutputFile, $Append, $Encoding

previousCommand.exe | ForEach-Object {
    $StreamWriter.WriteLine($_);
    $_;
}
$StreamWriter.Close();
```

My real suspicion, though, is that you may end up having to work very hard to get the system to take input in this encoding and to treat it correctly.